# Link to page when logging in to Facebook in xcode

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I've got my iPhone app running and what I want to achieve is when you navigate to a certain page, there is a button which, when clicked, will direct you to a certain page on Facebook. I have looked at the Facebook development pages (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/) for adding Facebook and it is currently opening up Facebook when clicked and logs in successfully, although not straight away like it should.

So my problems are as follows:

1) When the button is pressed, it should bring up a page asking for permission for my application to automatically log in but it doesn't,

2) When logged in, I want the app to take the user straight to a specific page on Facebook so they can look at it and like it but i have no idea how to do this,

3) I would also need a way of exiting the Facebook view, back to the previous view the user was on inside my application.

Thanks,

Matthew